# Excelからテキストと画像ファイルを同時に読み込みたい

Tags: python

python (2.7.10) で、エクセルからテキストと画像ファイルを読み込む方法について質問させていただきます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上記のように、エクセルファイルから行番号ごとにテキストと画像をペアで同時に読み込み、行番号を入力すると、そのテキストと画像を出したいと考えています。

ご教示いただければ幸いです。

Comment: Python 2.9？ 2.7ですか？

Comment: Python2.7です。修正しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python 2.7.10`で`PyQt`と`xlrd`を使って良いならば、下記のコードで最低限の要件は満たせると思いますが、いかがでしょうか。
※`Ubuntu 15.10`で検証

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import xlrd
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.resize(600, 480)
    w.setWindowTitle('test')
    global spin
    spin = QtGui.QSpinBox(w)
    spin.setMinimum(1)
    spin.setMaximum(3)
    button = QtGui.QPushButton("read", w)
    button.move(0, 30)
    button.clicked.connect(show_data)
    global label
    label = QtGui.QLabel('', w)
    label.setGeometry(0, 60, 200, 30)
    global image
    image = QtGui.QLabel('', w)
    image.setGeometry(0, 90, 200, 50)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def show_data():
    book = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xlsx')
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    row = spin.value()
    label.setText(sheet.cell(row,1).value)
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
    pixmap.load(sheet.cell(row,2).value)
    image.setPixmap(pixmap)
    image.resize(pixmap.size())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```